2000s teen sitcom episode - boy becomes addicted to RPG, two girls intervene
This was a TV episode that I watched some time around 2010. It was definitely made in the 2000s, and centred around a group of teenagers. It was an American show, but I watched it in the UK.
The episode's main plotline involves one of the male teens becoming addicted to an RPG named Dwarf Lord. I forget whether it's an MMO or a Dungeons and Dragons-style tabletop game, but it takes over his personality and becomes all he ever talks about. Two of his female friends decide they want his old self back, so they stage an "intervention" which, I now realize, may have been a parody of A Clockwork Orange.
They tie him to a chair, and first attempt "reverse psychology" by repeatedly saying "Dwarf Lord" and inflicting minor pain on him (I think they were putting sticky tape on his arm and ripping it off). The idea is that this will make him associate the game with pain. After that, they show him a montage of clips of his usual behaviour, and eventually he snaps and reverts back to his old personality - at that point he grabs a bag of potato chips and starts stuffing his face.
I tried Googling "Dwarf Lord", but it's such a generic name that it doesn't turn up anything relevant. Other than that, and the details I already mentioned, I have no idea what show this could possibly be.

You were just a space away from the answer... it's a Lizzie McGuire episode (ep. 27 from season 1) called Gordo and the Dwarves, from 2001.

Gordo becomes obsessed with a Dungeons & Dragons type board game which was gifted to Lizzie by her grandmother.

The game is called Dwarflord and Gordo's friends try to wean him off it exactly like you described. The episode is currently available online here, and here's the cast:


Lizzie McGuire! I knew it had to have been something I didn't watch regularly. This is definitely it, thanks!
